# How can I simplify/fasten this list flattening?

Tags: python-3.x

```
event_store: List[Event] = []
for event in self.misc.save():
    event_store.append(event)
for event in self.playlist.save():
    event_store.append(event)
for channel in self.channels:
    for event in channel.save():
        event_store.append(event)
for pattern in self.patterns:
    for event in pattern.save():
        event_store.append(event)
for arrangement in self.arrangements:
    for event in arrangement.save():
        event_store.append(event)
for insert in self.inserts:
    for event in insert.save():
        event_store.append(event)
event_store.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('index'))
```

*where **index** is an attribute of **Event***.

*and `save()` just returns `dict.values()` from a `Dict[str, Event]`*

I tried `itertools.chain` but `event_store` wasn't flattened like the code above does it.
I want this to be fast *if possible* as `event_store` has a minimum of 2500+ `Event` objects in it. I am using Python 3.10

Comment: As you are making function calls, the overall performance depends on the performance of those functions.

Comment: @trincot Yea, forgot to mention that `save()` just returns `dict.values()` from a `Dict[str, Event]`

Comment: Are you aware of ``list.extend``?

Comment: As far as the function calls are concerned,  `save()` in particular sounds like it could be doing disk or database accesses, in which case the efficiency or otherwise of anything in CPU and memory is likely to be relatively less important

Comment: @MisterMiyagi oh yea, i forgot that

Comment: @JiříBaum As I stated above ``save()`` just returns values from a dictionary, everything is in the memory. No disk use

Comment: If `save()` doesn't write to some form of permanent storage, it may be misnamed...

Answer (score 3):

```
event_store: List[Event] = []
for thing in [
    self.misc,
    self.playlist,
    *self.channels,
    *self.patterns,
    *self.arrangements,
    *self.inserts,
]:
    event_store.extend(thing.save())

event_store.sort(key=lambda e: e.index)
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, I don't know why this didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, more verbose, but no temporary list.

```py
event_store: List[Event] = list(chain(
    self.misc.save(),
    self.playlist.save(),
    chain.from_iterable(x.save() for x in chain(
        self.channels,
        self.patterns,
        self.arrangements,
        self.inserts,
    )),
))
event_store.sort(key=lambda e: e.index)
```

Comment: You should be able to unpack into a literal in this case as well, i.e. ``…= [*self.misc.save(), *self.playlist.save(), *chain.from_iterable(…)]``.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, here's the most efficient thing I can come up with. It happens to be a one-liner, interestingly.

```
import heapq
import itertools

event_store: list[Event] = list(heapq.merge(itertools.chain(
    self.misc.save(),
    self.playlist.save(),
    (event for channel in self.channels for event in channel.save()),
    (event for pattern in self.patterns for event in pattern.save()),
    (event for arrangement in self.arrangements for event in arrangement.save()),
    (event for insert in self.inserts for event in insert.save()),
), key=operator.attrgetter('index')))
```

There are two main problems you have to solve here. First, a particular flattening scheme where two items need to be flattened once and the rest need to be flattened twice. Second, you need these all sorted at the end of it all.

[`heapq.merge()` should be able to take care of both of these requirements at once](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge). Sorting the elements as we insert them will be slightly faster than sorting them all after they're already there, and if we use `itertools.merge()` as `heapq.merge()`'s first argument, this takes care of one layer of flattening for us already, so we only have to manually flatten one more layer when necessary. The idiom `[element for sublist in list for element in sublist]` is my go-to for flattening a single layer, and we can use it here for the remaining arguments.

If a generator will suffice instead of a list (may be more efficient speed or memory wise, you'd maybe have to experiment), then you can omit the surrounding `list()` call on `heapq.merge()`, since the latter returns a generator.

Comment: You're making the assumption that the events from each source are already in order? (This may or may not be true, depending on the situation.)

Comment: @JiříBaum just realized this. Edited my answer accordingly to incorporate `itertools.chain()` manually.

Comment: "Sorting the elements as we insert them will be slightly faster than sorting them all after they're already there" Are you sure of that? Iterator algorithms generally are *slower* because they have to jump in/out of the iterator repeatedly. I would assume bulk processing via ``list.extend`` and ``list.sort`` to be significantly faster.

Comment: The `heapq` methods are faster if (a) you need to alternate removing smallest elements and inserting new elements, or (b) you're overlapping them with I/O operations

Comment: The variable names are suggestive of both (a) and (b), but the question never actually states either...

Comment: This answer made me realise I have skipped quite a few details in my question. First, events returned by ``save()`` will be quite ordered already. Currently I don't support removing events, neither my code does it internally, but it will be a thing in the future. There will be no I/O operations whatsoever, during this entire operation. It is all in the memory entirely. The event store will only be dumped to the file after it is sorted